# Django : KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `channel` on serializer ``

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

model

```py
class Metric(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    impressions = models.IntegerField()
    clicks = models.IntegerField()    

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.date, self.channel)
```

My view

```py
class MetricViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = MetricSerializer
    queryset = Metric.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = MetricFilter
```

My serializer

```py
class MetricSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Metric
        fields = '__all__'
```

**I need to group by one or more columns: date, channel, country, operating system** and serialize it. Can someone help me with how I can do it?

```
select channel, country, sum(impressions) as impressions, sum(clicks) as clicks from sample dataset where date < '2017-06-01' group by channel, country order by clicks desc;
     channel      | country | impressions | clicks 
------------------+---------+-------------+--------
 adcolony         | US      |      532608 |  13089
 apple_search_ads | US      |      369993 |  11457
 vungle           | GB      |      266470 |   9430
 vungle           | US      |      266976 |   7937
```

My view

```py
lass MetricViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = MetricSerializer
    queryset = Metric.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = MetricFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        sort_by_dict = {'asc': '', 'desc': '-'}
        queryset = Metric.objects.all()        
        group_by = self.request.query_params.get('group_by', None)
        # grouping the queryset
        if group_by is not None:
            queryset = queryset.values(group_by).annotate(dcount=Count(group_by))#.order_by()               

        return queryset
```

I am getting the following error

```
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `channel` on serializer `MetricSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'channel'."
```

Comment: Since you changed the fields by using `values`, that needs to also reflect to your serializer. For example, that error came because the serializer expects the `channel` field, but it was probably removed by the `values(group_by)` call

Comment: Can you please tell me ,How to overcome this?

Comment: To give you an idea, you need to make your serializer flexible in handling dynamic set of fields. Have a look [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example). Once you have applied that, you can set the fields of your serializer to the same `group_by` fields you use in your queryset (plus the annotation you added)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, ( haven't tested)

```html
from django.db.models import Sum


queryset.values('channel', 'country').order_by().annotate(impressions = sum('impressions'),clicks = sum('clicks'))
```

Edit ---

Oh i missed some points of your question, I think you need to make small change to view and serializer

in that case

```
 if group_by is not None:       
    queryset = queryset.values(group_by).order_by().annotate(impressions = sum('impressions'),clicks = sum('clicks'))
```

And your Serializer able to handle optional fields

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MetricSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

         date = serializers.DateField()
         channel = title = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=50, allow_blank=True)
         country = title = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=10, allow_blank=True)
         os = title = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=10, allow_blank=True)
         impressions = serializers.IntegerField()
         clicks = serializers.IntegerField()
```